# postgres listen only runs when I do something

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following demo in postgres 9.6.

I did the following in this order:

I ran in PSQL: `LISTEN foo;`

I ran in DataGrip.  `NOTIFY foo,'thad man';`

Went back to the PSQL console and don't see my expected:

```
 Asynchronous notification "foo" with payload "thad man" received from server process with PID 4117.
```

It is only in PSQL when I run any statement do I get my notification. How might I be able to see notification are made without doing anything? Is this possible? If I have to run a statement like `SELECT 1;` what  benefit might I get from listening in the application layer? Would I have to be running `SELECT 1;` in a constant loop every second or something to get notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It is only in PSQL when I run any statement do I get my notification*

An application doesn't have to poll the database to receive notifications, but it has to poll the status of its socket (network connection) to know that there is a notification to collect, otherwise there's no way to know about it. psql doesn't do that when waiting on user input. It blocks on user input, as most command-line oriented applications.

> *Would I have to be running SELECT 1; in a constant loop every second
>   or something to get notified?*

No, but you need to implement some sort of event loop in your application to detect the notification and handle it. But neither the detection nor the handling need to send any query to the database server.

Answer (score 1):

This is how "psql" works.  When it is waiting for the keyboard, that is the only think it is waiting for.  Can you imagine how annoying it would be if messages were received and displayed while you were in the middle of typing?

Use some other tool, which is not principally designed for interactive work.  It is fairly easy to make a perl script, for example, which displays notices as fast as they arrive.  I think the latest JDBC makes it easier than it used to be to do this in JAVA as well.  I'd be surprised if Python doesn't have a solution, although I don't recall seeing/testing one.

Comment: So typically I don't even use psql unless I have to. Is there a way to select the results in datagrip or some other SQL IDE?

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with datagrip.

Comment: Ok. Might you know how this would work in pgadmin?